# How to override a JAMS extension

Tags: acumatica

After I installed the JAMS product for v2019R1, I notice the field SOOrder.customerOrderNbr has a different label.  I assume this happens, due to a graph or cache extension.  The client wishes to change the label.  Since I do not have the JAMS source code, what is the best way?
[image]

Comment: You can use the language translation feature to override this label with your own. It's possible to modify the English (US) labels. You'll have to run Collect Strings so that it picks up the "Release Nbr." string added by JAMS.

Comment: Not sure there is a best way, usually I just try every method until I find one that yields the desired outcome. I would try the CacheAttached method to override the DisplayName property first as it's one of the last mechanism that is applied so it would win the race to be the last one to set DisplayName property.

Answer (score 0):

I have JAMS installed, but it doesn't change my field name, however, my approach would be to:

- Add a new customization project
- Put a 2 in the "Level" column
- Add Screen SO301000
- Locate and change the Display Name to your desired text
- Publish your project

The key here is using the 2 in the "Level" column to resolve a conflict. See [Acumatica Wiki reference for details](https://help-2017r2.acumatica.com/Wiki/ShowWiki.aspx?pageid=d9d57482-8c8f-4f29-9168-b56b81834d9e)